# List of recently cast close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Is there some place where I can see a list of my recently cast close votes?
They don't appear to show up in my activity feed.

In case it's not possible, it would be nice to be able to look back at recently cast votes, in case the OP updates / fixes his question.

Comment: close votes that you have cast? or that anyone has cast?

Comment: Yes, like I said: _"my recently cast close votes"_.

Comment: In the [Close Votes Review Queue](http://stackexchange.com/review/close/history?userId=1835379) you can also find your latest close votes, but only those you cast via the review process.

Comment: @Werner, that actually is a good answer. It doesn't completely answer my question, but I think it's useful information for someone that might be looking for recent close votes.

Comment: "*They don't appear to show up in my activity feed.*" keep going along, that's it, no that's 'responses' a little more, there! :P

Comment: [_"Wait, how'd I miss that -.-"_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274939/list-of-recently-cast-close-votes?noredirect=1#comment108175_274940) Famous last words...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can view the close votes you have cast here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=votes&sort=closure

You can find your close vote history by going to your profile, clicking on ***votes*** and then ***closure***.

Comment: Wait, how'd I miss that -.-

Comment: @Cerbrus: that is a good question...